# Where file created in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Console program creates file, e.g `File "text.txt"` when I run program in NetBeans.
Where does NetBeans store this file?

Comment: At least for netbeans type projects, the file gets stored in the root project directory

Comment: If you've changed nothing else, it will most likely be created in the root project folder

Comment: It's pointing to the working directory. Where that is depends on a number of variables.

Comment: root dir doesn't contain any files created. I checked it before I asked.

Answer (score 0):

This file will be created in the same directory that your program is in. This is most likely the projects folder, although this is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

If no specific path was provided when creating the file (see code below), then file gets created in your project directory.

```
File file = new File("newfile.txt");
```

You can find your project directory by going to the "Netbeans "Projects" tab, right-clicking in your project folder and selecting "Properties". The "Project folder" will be shown on at the top of the new window displayed (i.e. "C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\YourProjectName"). That directory will include the newfile.txt created.